# getting an error once trying to retrieve data with NODEJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I have a little issue trying to perform a `get` in my app.

first this is the error in the browser console

```
GET http://localhost:1337/sports/getChecked/12787fb1e00a01337f0508ca47223d15
401 (Unauthorized)
code.min.js:875 Object {err: "JSON request needed"}
code.min.js:543 Error {stack: (...)}
code.min.js:967 ["3042", "59321H", "5932"]
code.min.js:690 ["3042", "59321H", "5932"]
```

I am doing a `post` and in the `post` everything is fine so far, the issue is in the `get`, I am working with Json web tokens (JWT)...

these are the routes for `post` and `get`

```
module.exports.routes = {
   'post /sports/checked': 'SetSportsController.setCheck',
   'get /sports/getChecked/:user': 'SetSportsController.retrieveSetCheck'
};
```

here the policies

```
module.exports.policies = {
 setCheck: ['jwtAuth', 'sanitizerPolicy', 'headersPolicy', 'sessionKiller'],
 retrieveSetCheck: ['jwtAuth', 'sanitizerPolicy', 'sessionKiller']
};
```

`get` on **SetSportController.js**

```
  retrieveSetCheck: function(req, res) {
    if (req.params) {
      SportSelectionService.getSportChecked(req.params).then(function(sportChecked) {
        console.log(sportChecked.sport);
        res.json(200, sportChecked);
      }, function(err) {
        res.json(400, err);
      });
    }else {
      res.json(400, {error: 'Error retrieving Sports'});
    }
  }
```

**SportSelectionService.js**

```
  getSportChecked: function(params) {
    var Promise = require('bluebird');
    return new Promise(function(fullfill, reject) {
      console.time('sportChecked_findOne');
      SportSelection.find({
        user: params.user
      }).exec(function(err, sportChecked) {
        console.timeEnd('sportChecked_findOne');
        if (err) {
          reject(new Error('Error finding favorite leagues'));
          console.error(err);
        }else {
          if (sportChecked) {
            fullfill(sportChecked.sport);
          }else {
            console.time('sportChecked_create');
            SportSelection.create({
              sport: [],
              user: params.user
            }).exec(function(err, created) {
              console.timeEnd('sportChecked_create');
              console.log(err);
              console.log(created);
              if (err) {
                reject(new Error('Error on sportChecked'));
              }else {
                fullfill(created);
                fullfill(created.sport);
              }
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
```

**this is the FRONT-END part**

```
  <ion-item ng-click="toggleSportSelection(sport)">
    {{:: sport.name}}
  </ion-item>
```

**controller.js**

```
SportsFactory.getSportChecked(customer).then(function(sportChecked) {
        console.log(sportChecked);
        _.each(sports, function(sport) {
          var sportIds = _.pluck(sport, 'id'),
              intersectedSports = _.intersection(sportIds, sportChecked),
              checkedSportObjects = _.filter(sport, function(sportObj) {
                return _.includes(intersectedSports, sportObj.sportIds);
              });
          _.each(checkedSportObjects, function(sport) {
            $scope.sportObj.push(sport);
          });
        });
      });

$scope.toggleSportSelection = function(sport) {
  var params = {};
  params.user = $scope.customer.customer;
  params.sport = sport.id;
  sport.checked = !sport.checked;
  SportsFactory.setSportChecked(params);
};
```

**service.js**

```
  getSportChecked: function(customer) {
    var defer = $q.defer(),
        user,
        rejection = function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          defer.reject(err);
        };
    LocalForageFactory.retrieve(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_SPORTS_CHECKED)
      .then(function(sportChecked) {
        user = customer.customer;
        if (!_.isNull(sportChecked)) {
          defer.resolve(sportChecked);
        }else {
          $http.get(CONSTANT_VARS.BACKEND_URL + '/sports/getChecked/' + user)
          .success(function(sportChecked) {
            LocalForageFactory.set(CONSTANT_VARS.LOCALFORAGE_FAVORITE_LEAGUES, sportChecked);
            defer.resolve(sportChecked);
          })
          .error(rejection);
        }
      }, rejection);
    return defer.promise;
  }
```

looking on the files project I got this file named `headersPolicy.js` which looks like this

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
  var _ = require('lodash');
  if (!_.isNull(req.headers)) {
    /* This API only accepts JSON, we could send 406 response, but we don't want
     * to give any kind of clues ;)
     */
    if (!req.is('json')) {
      return res.json(401, {err: 'JSON request needed'});
    }
    next();
  }else {
    /*
    * No headers, wrong request
    * */
    return res.json(401, {err: 'Headers not present'});
  }
};
```

so where is this error coming from ? what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

The middleware below is checking (presumably) whether the Content-Type header is set to 'application/json'. Since you're sending a GET and not a POST request, that header is most likely not application/json.

```
    if (!req.is('json')) {
      return res.json(401, {err: 'JSON request needed'});
    }
```

Comment: so how can I avoid that? what changes do I have to perform in my code ?

Comment: You need to show how you're making use of this: module.exports.policies = {
 setCheck: ['jwtAuth', 'sanitizerPolicy', 'headersPolicy', 'sessionKiller'],
 retrieveSetCheck: ['jwtAuth', 'sanitizerPolicy', 'sessionKiller']
};

Comment: I've been doing lots of post and get in this app, and this is the 1st get giving me that kind of issues.

Comment: afaik you won't get json on a GET request, so you need skip that check when method is GET  `if(req.method !== 'GET'){     if (!req.is('json')) {
      return res.json(401, {err: 'JSON request needed'});
    } }`